# Getting "subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector" error and I don't know why

Tags: c, struct, cs50, bubble-sort

```
// Practice working with structs
// Practice applying sorting algorithms

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_CITIES 10

typedef struct
{
    string city;
    int temp;
}
avg_temp;

avg_temp temps[NUM_CITIES];

void sort_cities(void);

int main(void)
{
    temps[0].city = "Austin";
    temps[0].temp = 97;

    temps[1].city = "Boston";
    temps[1].temp = 82;

    temps[2].city = "Chicago";
    temps[2].temp = 85;

    temps[3].city = "Denver";
    temps[3].temp = 90;

    temps[4].city = "Las Vegas";
    temps[4].temp = 105;

    temps[5].city = "Los Angeles";
    temps[5].temp = 82;

    temps[6].city = "Miami";
    temps[6].temp = 97;

    temps[7].city = "New York";
    temps[7].temp = 85;

    temps[8].city = "Phoenix";
    temps[8].temp = 107;

    temps[9].city = "San Francisco";
    temps[9].temp = 66;

    sort_cities();

    printf("\nAverage July Temperatures by City\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CITIES; i++)
    {
        printf("%s: %i\n", temps[i].city, temps[i].temp);
    }
}

// TODO: Sort cities by temperature in descending order
void sort_cities(void)
{
    // Add your code here
    int swap_counter = 1;
    int origtemp = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int n;
    if (strlen(temps[j+1].city) > strlen(temps[j].city))
        {
            n = strlen(temps[j+1].city);
        }
        else if (strlen(temps[j+1].city) < strlen(temps[j].city))
        {
            n = strlen(temps[j].city);
        }
        else
        {
            n = strlen(temps[j].city);
        }
    do
    {
        while (swap_counter > 0)
        {
            swap_counter--;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
        {
            origtemp += temps[i].temp;
            if (temps[i].temp > temps[i + 1].temp)
            {
                swap_counter++;
                while (temps[i].temp > temps[i + 1].temp)
                {
                    temps[i].temp--;
                }
                while (temps[i+1].temp < origtemp)
                {
                    temps[i].temp;
                }
                for (int b = 0; b < n; b++)
                {
                    temps[i][b].city = temps[i+1][b].city;
                    if (temps[i][b].city == '\0')
                    {
                        temps[i][b+1].city = '\0';
                        temps[i][b].city = temps[i+1][b].city;
                    }
                    if (temps[i+1][b].city == '\0')
                    {
                        temps[i][b].city = '\0';
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                while (origtemp > 0)
                {
                    origtemp--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (swap_counter != 0);
    return temps[i].city, temps[i].temp;
}
```

The error happens on the line which is:

```
temps[i][b].city = temps[i+1][b].city;
```

What i'm trying to do is swap each character of `temps[i][b].city` with `temps[i+1][b].city` with special conditions. If `temps[i][b].city` == to `NULL` at any point, `NULL` is moved forward so the character of `temps[i+1][b].city` can replace it. If `temps[i+1][b].city` is equal to `NULL`, that means that the word is shorter, so `temps[i][b].city` is just cut off right there and it breaks. The problem is that it's not letting me go into each character of the arrays.

This is actually a cs50 problem, and the point is to try and sort the temperature of different locations by lowest to highest. To do this, I have chosen to use bubble sort. If the temperature of the first location is higher than the second location, the temperatures and the locations are swapped. We run this over and over until the entire thing is sorted. To swap the letters of the locations, I want to just go over each character of the arrays and swap them, while still taking in account `NULL`. However, when I try this, I get an error.

Comment: @Harr It seems you mean for example temps[i].city[b] = temps[i+1].city[b]; instead of temps[i][b].city = temps[i+1][b].city;. But in any case the presented code does not make sense.

Comment: I added all the code

Comment: `temps` is a one-dimensional array. Therefore, it does not make sense to for example write `temps[i][b]`. That would only make sense with a two-dimensional array (i.e. an array of arrays). As stated by someone else, you probably mean `temps[i].city[b]` instead.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I think that the question should not be reopened becuase my previous comment in fact is an answer to the question. He should read comments.

Comment: You have more problems than the one you're asking about. Just looking at the very end of your code. You have undeclared identifiers `i` and `loops`. At the end of your `sort_cities` function, this: `while (swap_counter != 0);` either does nothing or does nothing forever, and this: `return temps[i].city, temps[i].temp;` makes no sense (the function doesn't return a value, and you're misusing the comma operator).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow If  you want to answer the question, post an answer. And answering a question doesn't mean it should be closed. There might be other valid reasons to close the question.

Comment: In your struct, because you use `string` [this is a cs50 typedef for `char *`], you do _not_ want to swap char-by-char. The `.city` values are _pointers_ to string _literals_ in read-only memory. Your swap should be the _entire_ struct: `avg_temp tmp = temps[i]; temps[i] = temps[i + 1]; temps[i + 1] = tmp;`

Comment: @KeithThompson The question was already closed. I pointed out a mistake in the first original incomplete snippet of the code. He should take into account my comment and at least update using the subscript operator.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Are you saying he should update the code to correct the problem he was asking about? That would invalidate the question.

Comment: @KeithThompson Before reopening teh question using teh subscript operator in the code should be updated. That is he got enough information that he is using the subscript operator incorrectly. In this case there will be one problem less. And the title of the question would be different.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Changing the code in a question to address the problem being asked about is inappropriate. Possibly the OP should ask a new question.

Comment: @KeithThompson Address this comment to the author of the question.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Why? You advised the OP to update the code in the question to address the problem he asked about. I addressed my comment to you. (And I'm done here.)

Comment: @KeithThompson It seems you need to reread my comments at least one more time. I said that the question as is should not be reopened. Is it clear?

Comment: Strongly suggest you avoid the use of global variables. Also, you can initialize the array as: `avg_temp temps[] = {{"Austin", 97}, {"Boston", 82}, {"Chicago", 85}, ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a single dimensional array like it's a two dimensional array. That is the error you're seeing.

Your sorting seems overly complex. You have stated you wish to use bubble sort. That's acceptable for such a small sample size.

Assuming we stick with the less than ideal global variable `temps`, there are only two cases where we need to swaps two cities: if the temp is higher in the first city, or if the temps are the same and the first name is "greater" than the second.

```
void sort_cities(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CITIES - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_CITIES - i - 1; j++) {
            if (temps[j].temp < temps[j+1].temp) { 
                continue;
            }
            
            if (temps[j].temp > temps[j+1]) {
                avg_temp tmp = temps[j];
                temps[j] = temps[j+1];
                temps[j+1] = tmp;
                continue;
            }

            int name_cmp = strcmp(temps[j].city, temps[j+1].city);

            if (name_cmp == 1) {
                avg_temp tmp = temps[j];
                temps[j] = temps[j+1];
                temps[j+1] = tmp;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

This might be simplified to avoid writing two swaps.

```
void sort_cities(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CITIES - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_CITIES - i - 1; j++) {
            if (temps[j].temp > temps[j+1].temp || 
                (temps[j].temp == temps[j+1].temp && 
                 strcmp(temps[j].city, temps[j+1].city) == 1)) {
                avg_temp tmp = temps[j];
                temps[j] = temps[j+1];
                temps[j+1] = tmp;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```